# What's the difference between input `file.stream()` vs `response.body` if I only want to get the stream in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

Please see this minimum example:

I want to get the **stream** of the mp3 file, I've found two ways to do this, I am confusing about which one should I use.

1. `file.stream()` can get the file stream
2. pass the file to `createObjectURL`, and `fetch` the URL, and I can get the stream from `response.body`

Are they identical?

Which one is better if I only want to get the stream?

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("change", async () => {
  const file = input.files[0];
  const response = await fetch(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));

  console.log("Stream from fetch response body", response.body);
  console.log("Stream from file.stream()", file.stream());
});
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="audio/mp3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `file.stream` because you already have the `File` object available to you.

Don't use `createObjectURL` (i.e. your example with `fetch`) if you already have a `File` or `Stream` available because you're just creating needless work for the browser.

<sub>(I speculate that's because JavaScript doesn't define the lifetime of, or how to manage the state of, external resources that browsers may create "safe" copies of data in this case, rather than having the `Response`' `Stream` share the same underlying byte-bufffer)</sub>.

As you're wondering: the `createObjectURL` function is used to generate a **string URI** that you can pass to other objects that can't work with a `Stream` or `File` object, such as a `<video>` element's `src` attribute - this is how you can show an instant preview of an image file or video from an `<input type="file" />` without needing to do anything inefficient like using a Base64-encoded `data:` URI or upload the file to your web-server first.

Also, whenever you use `createObjectURL`, you **have** to call `revokeObjectURL()` otherwise you'll have a memory-leak in your browser until your page is unloaded.